# I try to run my venv in python, however I ger errors, terminal says The term '.\venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, reactjs, virtualenv

I am react js developer and I want to run the backend part of my code, the backend dev said me to download python and run the following commands in webstorm terminal.

## Activate virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
python .\manage.py runserver
```

When I try to do it, I get errors, which I cannot fix. The error below.

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate : The term '.\venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+  .\venv\Scripts\activate
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\venv\Scripts\activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

Please help me to activate python server

Comment: just do vent\script\activate; no need of the .\ at start I mean .

Comment: you're in powershell so you need to use Activate.ps1

Comment: now I got an error of  The module 'venv' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module venv'.

Comment: I guess I was thinking in terms of windows cmd prompt. In poweshell it should be a bit different maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using PowerShell, use the following command:

```
.\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Make sure the capitalization is correct.

Comment: bro can you give me the commands that I should run in the webstorm terminal?

Comment: I did. The prompt should say `PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\OK_COMPANY`. Copy and paste `.\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` into the prompt and hit Enter. Next, put in `python .\manage.py runserver` and hit Enter, and you should be all set.